# Задача на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

В оранжерее школы есть система автоматического полива. Она состоит из трубочек, насосов и ёмкостей. У каждого растения есть своя отдельная ёмкость для воды и удобрений. Все ёмкости подключены друг к другу трубочками по цепочке. Они равномерно наполняются.
Система автополива отлично проработала весь год. Летом во время ремонта её разобрали, а потом собрали неправильно. Оказалось, что в системе появились зацикливания, и некоторые растения перестали получать питательные вещества и воду.
Совет самоуправления решил назначить дежурных и поливать растения вручную. Чтобы всё наладить, нужно узнать, сколько растений неправильно подключено к [системе](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J3Uh0USrUfaPoAIiYPhUVH7kb1-s5dGm/view?usp=sharing).

Входные данные:
В первой строке — количество растений, подключенных к системе автоматического полива, 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000.
В следующих i = 1...N строках — номера ёмкостей растений, к которым идёт трубочка из ёмкости растения с номером i.

Пример:

```
5
2
3
1
0
4

Ответ: 3
```

На рисунке представлена схема соединения растений.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ёмкости растений 1, 2 и 3 зациклены. Ёмкость растения 4 последняя в цепочке, от неё никуда не идёт трубка. В итоге в системе орошения 2 незацикленные ёмкости: 4 и 5.**

Ссылка на документ, в котором представлены данные: [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J3Uh0USrUfaPoAIiYPhUVH7kb1-s5dGm/view?usp=sharing).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную задачку на Python.

Comment: На каком этапе решения у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: @andreymal честно сказать на этапе понимания того, как нужно решать эту задачу на python...

Comment: Тогда можно начать с написания или отрисовки алгоритма действий без привязки к языку. А потом уже пошагово реализовывать на python, уже конкретно разбираясь в синтаксисе того или иного действия.

Comment: @workonyourself ну тогда наверное стоит начать с чтения учебников по python